# react-native-firebase receiving notification when app in running

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, notifications

I'm implementing push notification using react-native-firebase.  So, I'm testing the cloud messaging. I could receive the notification when screen is off and in background. But, I couldn't receive notification when the app on running. Are there any problem in my code or do i need to add some code?

```
async createNotificationListeners() {

    this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications.onNotification((notification) => {
        const { title, body } = notification;
        this.showAlert(title, body);
    });

    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
        const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
        this.showAlert(title, body);
    });

    const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
        const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
        this.showAlert(title, body);
    }

    this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
        //process data message
        console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.notificationListener();
    this.notificationOpenedListener();
}
```

Comment: why would you want to send out notifications to a user that is using your app at this moment? that seems like a really annoying user experience. if you want to have some kind of notifications during your app is being used try to implement some kind of inapp notification that comes up in some natural pauses during the app usage

Answer (score 0):

**Push Notifications** cannot occur *in App* because that is actually contrary to it's a purpose. A reasonable [definition](https://searchmobilecomputing.techtarget.com/definition/push-notification) of a push notification is the delivery of information from a software application to a computing device without a specific request from the client. During app use, the client would be making specific requests to the server. You should handle the notifications differently like using a numbered Icon for example. You could also explore [Firebase In-App Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/in-app-messaging/?gclid=CjwKCAiAl7PgBRBWEiwAzFhmmqcfnC3PfDIal5LSudxsNuKlCUT2YBSkgX5q-FdO0zYG3O1cRXHnrRoCdfoQAvD_BwE) for a more engaging experience.